# Sobre animacion css3

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap-4

Resulta que estoy haciendo una pagina html con el framework animate.css y bootstrap4. Tengo un div al cual le he agregado una animacion pero quiero que esta se repita cada vez que se observa el elemento y no cuando se entra en la web, es decir en estos momentos el div se anima cuando uno entra a la pagina o al recargar, y como esta ubicado abajo de otro contenido no se alacanza a observar la animacion.
O si es posible una alternativa por favor, he buscado mucho en internet y no encuentro nada.

Codigo html:

```
<div id="anim" class="col-12 border caja animated fadeIn">      
   <h1>Algunas aves que solo se encuentran en colombia</h1>
</div>
```

La clase caja no efecta en nada.

Web animate.css
https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Answer (score 0):

Creo que en el div del css debería emplear `infinite` por ejemplo:

```
div {
  ....
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  ....
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

Aquí una simple [animación](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FRTQ2AI4VF8H) sólo dale click a `Run >>`

Answer (score 0):

Tambien he tenido ese mismo problema con el Animate.css y es que solo funciona para reproducir la animación al recargar la pagina o repetirla infinitamente con la propiedad infinited, si eso es lo que quieres puedes ponerlo de la siguiente manera.

```
<div id="anim" class="col-12 border caja animated infinited fadeIn">
```